# Rails User ID in an associated model, why can't I call the User's information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, has-many

I have a meetings table that has a requester_id and requestee_id which are both user ids (using devise).

```
create_table "meetings", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "requestor_id"
 t.integer  "requestee_id"
 t.datetime "meeting_time"
 t.boolean  "accepted"
 t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
```

When calling the requestor_id.first_name:

View

```
<tbody>
 <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= meeting.requestor_id %></td>
    <td><%= @requestor.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.requestee_id %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.meeting_time %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.accepted %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', meeting %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meeting_path(meeting) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', meeting, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Controller

```
 def show
  @requestor = User.find(params[:requestor_id])
 end
```

It says undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

I'm not sure if this has any relevance, but when I rake routes, none of the meetings have a path for some reason. It just says:

```
PUT    /languages_users/:id(.:format)               languages_users#update
DELETE /languages_users/:id(.:format)               languages_users#destroy
GET    /meetings(.:format)                          meetings#index
POST   /meetings(.:format)                          meetings#create
GET    /meetings/new(.:format)                      meetings#new
GET    /meetings/:id/edit(.:format)                 meetings#edit
GET    /meetings/:id(.:format)                      meetings#show
PATCH  /meetings/:id(.:format)                      meetings#update
PUT    /meetings/:id(.:format)                      meetings#update
DELETE /meetings/:id(.:format)                      meetings#destroy
```

some of my config/routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :meetings
   resources :meetings

   devise_for :users

   root 'welcome#index'
  end
```

app/model/meetings.rb

```
  class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
  end
```

How can I call the User table, with the integer in the requestor_id, and requestee_id. As well, conceptually what am I missing or not understanding here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show two files? 1. Can you show your `config/routes.rb` file. 1. Can you show a portion of your `app/models/meetings.rb` file? Specifically, the portion where you have defined any relationships such as with `has_many`, `has_one`, or `belongs_to`?

Comment: Yes! added now. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Your code seems like it should work. I'd guess that the problem is your `params[:requestor_id]`. Maybe you are not sending the id correctly or you are but the id doesn't match an existing user in the database. You could put `p params[:requestor_id]` at the start of your show action and see what it outputs to the controller.

Comment: *outputs to the **console** sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice a few opportunities for improvement in the code you've provided.

First, it appears as though you have `resources :meetings` listed twice in your routes file. That may have been a copy-paste error on your part into your Stack Overflow question, or, if that is the actual code, it may be why you say "none of the meetings have a path for some reason."

Independent of that, let's look at a subset of your `rake: routes`, specifically your `meetings#show` route:

```
GET    /meetings/:id(.:format)                      meetings#show
```

With this resourceful route, you get `params[:id]` sent to your controller, in this case, the id of a meeting.

Now, one piece that confuses me. In your view code, you refer to `@meetings`, making me think this is the **index** view, and not the **show** view, where I would expect to see a variable called `@meeting`. I'm going to move forward right now discussing your show action. However, I'll circle back to your index view at the end.

In your show controller action, you have the line:

```
@requestor = User.find(params[:requestor_id])
```

However, your route is not providing a `requestor_id` to the params hash, which means you're calling `User.find(nil)`. With the Controller code as written, I would be expecting you to be hitting an error along the lines of: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=` or something similar when hitting show.

What you want to do instead is Find your Meeting, and get the Requestor based off the found Meeting.

So you could do something like this in your controller:

**app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
  @requestor = User.find(@meeting.requestor_id)
end
```

...at which point I would expect your view to render correctly. However, there's a more Rails-y way to do this, which takes me to your meetings model. Here are the relationships I would define:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :requested, class_name: "User"
end
```

From [the Rails Guide for the `belongs_to` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference):

> **4.1.2.2 :class_name**
>
> If the name of the other model cannot be derived from the association
>   name, you can use the :class_name option to supply the model name.

Unless your User model has a column titled `meeting_id`, I suspect your `Meeting.users` association is not wired up to do anything.

The associations I've written above works even though you don't actually have a table called Requestor. Instead you specify that both requestors and requestees are just special kinds of Users. That way, you don't need to define `@requestor` in your Controller at all, leaving you instead with...

**app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @meetings = Meeting.all
end
```

...and in your index view (I told you I'd come back to it)...

**app/views/meetings/index.html.erb**

```
 <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= meeting.requestor.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.requestee.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.meeting_time %></td>
    <td><%= meeting.accepted %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', meeting %></td>
```

...and so on...

Let me know if that makes sense!

Comment: This has been an incredible help, and I really appreciate the detailed response.  One thing I'm getting hung up on while working through this is, do I need to change 'requestor_id' in my Meetings table to 'requestor', or am I working with both of those? Thanks!

Comment: The common Rails pattern is that if you have a relationship such as `belongs_to :requestor`, it assumes you have a column called `requestor_id` and the actual user can be referenced by calling `@meeting.requestor`. (Note, you can get just the ID itself always by calling `@meeting.requestor_id`, and in practice that's much less frequent than just getting the requestor object). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try eager loading?

@meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id]).includes(:requestor)

@requestor = @meeting.requestor